I received npm gulp watch errors
[15:27:58] The following tasks did not complete: watch, <series>, <parallel>, css, js Did you forget to signal async completion? node:events:495 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^
I keep receiving this error when I try to run.
npx gulp watch

I downloaded the template from this link - Start Bootstrap (https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-2)
I have tried asking ChatGPT to fix it, but the problem persists.
Here is my gulpfile.mjs and package.json codes.
//gulpfile.mjs
"use strict";

// Load plugins
import browsersync from "browser-sync";
import del from "del";
import gulp from "gulp";
import merge from "merge-stream";
import plumber from "gulp-plumber";
import rename from "gulp-rename";
import sass from "gulp-dart-sass";
import uglify from "gulp-uglify";

// BrowserSync
function browserSync(done) {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./",
    },
    port: 3000,
  });
  done(); // Signal completion
}

// BrowserSync reload
function browserSyncReload(done) {
  browsersync.reload();
  done(); // Signal completion
}

// Clean vendor
function clean() {
  return del(["./vendor/"]); // No async signaling needed as `del` returns a promise
}

// Bring third party dependencies from node_modules into vendor directory
function modules() {
  const bootstrapJS = gulp
    .src("./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/*")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./vendor/bootstrap/js"));
  const bootstrapSCSS = gulp
    .src("./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/**/*")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./vendor/bootstrap/scss"));
  const chartJS = gulp
    .src("./node_modules/chart.js/dist/*.js")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./vendor/chart.js"));
  const dataTables = gulp
    .src([
      "./node_modules/datatables.net/js/*.js",
      "./node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/*.js",
      "./node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/*.css",
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./vendor/datatables"));
  const fontAwesome = gulp
    .src("./node_modules/@fortawesome/**/*")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./vendor"));
  const jqueryEasing = gulp
    .src("./node_modules/jquery.easing/*.js")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./vendor/jquery-easing"));
  const jquery = gulp
    .src([
      "./node_modules/jquery/dist/*",
      "!./node_modules/jquery/dist/core.js",
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./vendor/jquery"));
  return merge(
    bootstrapJS,
    bootstrapSCSS,
    chartJS,
    dataTables,
    fontAwesome,
    jquery,
    jqueryEasing
  );
}

// CSS task
function css() {
  return gulp
    .src("./scss/**/*.scss") // Correctly initiate a stream
    .pipe(plumber()) // Prevent pipeline breaking on errors
    .pipe(
      sass({
        outputStyle: "expanded",
      }).on("error", sass.logError)
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./css")) // Save compiled CSS
    .pipe(browsersync.stream()); // Stream changes to BrowserSync
}

// JS task
function js() {
  return gulp
    .src(["./js/*.js", "!./js/*.min.js"]) // Start with gulp.src
    .pipe(plumber()) // Handle errors
    .pipe(uglify()) // Minify JS
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" })) // Rename minified files
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./js")) // Save output
    .pipe(browsersync.stream()); // Stream changes to BrowserSync
}

// Watch files
function watchFiles(done) {
  gulp.watch("./scss/**/*.scss", css);
  gulp.watch(["./js/**/*.js", "!./js/**/*.min.js"], js);
  gulp.watch("./**/*.html", browserSyncReload);
  done(); // Signal completion
}

// Define complex tasks
const vendor = gulp.series(clean, modules);
const build = gulp.series(vendor, gulp.parallel(css, js));
const watch = gulp.series(build, gulp.parallel(watchFiles, browserSync));

// Export tasks
export { css, js, clean, vendor, build, watch };
export default build;

//package.json
{
  "title": "Dummy",
  "name": "Dummy",
  "version": "4.1.3",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/gulp watch"
  },
  "description": "An open source Bootstrap 4 admin theme.",
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "sass",
    "html",
    "responsive",
    "theme",
    "template",
    "admin",
    "app"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-2",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/issues",
    "email": "feedback@startbootstrap.com"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "Start Bootstrap",
  "contributors": [
    "David Miller (https://davidmiller.io/)"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.15.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "chart.js": "2.9.4",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.13.11",
    "fancy-log": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.6.0",
    "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
    "plugin-error": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.3",
    "del": "6.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^9.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "4.3.0",
    "gulp-dart-sass": "1.0.2",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-rename": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "3.0.2",
    "merge-stream": "2.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.58.0"
  }
}

Please help me, and thank you for your time.

Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: Did you forget to signal async completion?

@gre_gor Thanks for the link, but I've already read it. Forgot to mention it in the post.
I am still trying to understand it however. Unfortunately haven't solved it yet. Gonna keep trying.
